# ClassName+CoreDataClass.swift not generated in Xcode10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I updated my Xcode from 9.4.1 to 10 (stable release) and I'm trying to update my Core Data model. I set the Codegen to Manual/None as before, but when I do `Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclass` it generates only the file `<className>.CoreDataProperties.swift`, but not the `<className>.CoreDataClass.swift` one. The problem is that even if I create this file manually, Core Data doesn't recognize properties belonging to this Core Data entity.

What can I do?
Thank you very much

Comment: Tested in Xcode 10.0 (10A255) on an entity with Codegen set to Manual/None and it created both of those files for me. What does your manual file look like?

Comment: I have the same version too and the problem was a name conflict: make sure you move to trash the +CoreDataClass and +CoreDataProperties file before generating the new ones. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question if that's resolved your issue.